# What is the difference between "int *a = new int" and "int *a = new int()"?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between following two lines ?

```
int *a = new int;

int *a = new int();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int *a = new int;
```

`a` is pointing to **default-initialized** object (which is **uninitialized** object in *this* case i.e the value is *indeterminate* as per the Standard).

```
int *a = new int();
```

`a` is pointing to **value-initialized** object (which is **zero-initialized** object in *this* case i.e the value is *zero* as per the Standard).

Comment: C++11 § 8.5,p7, C++11 § 8.5,p5, and C++11 § 8.5,p6 for value-initializing, zero-initializing, and default-initializing, respectively, in case the OP is interested (and I highly doubt it).

Comment: Note that testing may not expose this difference: unlike for automatic storage, dynamically allocated memory will often end up as zero in simple test programs, and only contain "garbage" in larger programs when earlier memory gets reused.

Answer (score 6):

The first variant *default-initializes* the dynamically allocated `int`, which for built-in types such as `int` does not perform any initialization.

The second variant *value-initializes* it, which for `int` means *zero-initialization*, giving it value `0`.